# Special behavior built into Object() constructor

Tags: javascript

I am going through a book which says,

> The ***Object()*** constructor has even more special behavior built into it.
>   If you pass a more ***specific native object type*** as the parameter to the
>   ***Object() constructor***, it will actually ***type-detect*** and return the
>   ***proper native object type, constructed automatically***.

For instance,

> ***new Object("foo")*** will result the same as if you called ***new
>   String("foo").***

How can these two things be the same.

But

```
alert(new Object("foo") === new String("foo"));  // false
```

What exactly does the author mean by the above sentence(***new Object("foo")*** will result the same ...)?

Comment: I think it means that calling the `Object` constructor with a string will return a `String` object. In practise you should never really use either and simply let javascript detect it using syntax.

Comment: IMO the author is a bit imprecise. *"you pass a more specific native object type"*. a) You don't pass types, you pass values. b) `"foo"` does not produce a value of type object, it produces a value of type string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, you cannot use `===` to compare objects.  What that does is check to see if both are the *same* object (not if they have the same value(s)).

What the paragraph is saying is the following:

```
new Object("foo") => new String("foo")
new Object(3) => new Number(3)
new Object(true) => new Boolean(true)
new Object([]) => new Array()
```

So, instead of returning an `Object`, it figures out what you passed it and returns you an object of *that* type.

There's never any reason to do this.  You shouldn't do `new Object("foo")` or `new String("foo")`, you should just do `"foo"`.

Here's the *native* types:

```
new Object() => {}
new Array() => []
new String('foo') => 'foo'
new Number(3) => 3
new Boolean(true) => true
```

Answer (score 1):

Primitives like strings and numbers are compared by their value, while objects like arrays, dates, and plain objects are compared by their reference. That comparison by reference basically checks to see if the objects given refer to the same location in memory, which they do not, so the comparison is false.

You can't compare object's with `==` or `===` sign

but you can convert it to string then you can check string comparer

Try like this

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Object("foo")) === JSON.stringify(new String("foo")));
```

Comment: The topic is titled "special behavior built into it into Object() constructor" and the essential question is "What exactly does the author mean by the above sentence(new Object("foo") will result the same ...)?". Your correctly identified the mistake of comparing the references, but your answer focuses on string / reference comparison, not the question itself.